# Why is kinetic energy neglected here?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, energy-conservation, work

[image]

> It is given that the spring is in natural condition and we have to find the minimum mass of A for block B to leave the ground.

I worked out till here:  Since this is an isolated system mechanical energy will be conserved.

For Block B to lose contact:    k$x_m $=Mg which will give $x_m$=Mg/k.

Now since mechanical energy will be conserved therefore

$\frac 12 $k$x_{m}^2$+$\frac 12$$m_A$$v^2$+$\frac 12$$m$$v^2$=mg$x_m$.

But my book is neglecting the kinetic energies of these masses and they have not given any reason for it....can you tell me the reason for neglecting them even though visualising this scenario prompts us to think they are non-zero.

Comment: Is that equation *useful* to you? It introduces another unknown variable $v$, so it doesn't help you solve for anything. (And the two $v$'s are different in general, so it's even worse than that).

Comment: @ ChrisI know introducing another variable will make things worse that's why i want to know the reason behind their negations

Comment: As you say, using the energy equations doesn't help you. So why bring up energy at all?

Comment: I get the feeling the question can't be solved - there needs to be given a maximum extension of the spring.

Comment: @Chris I don't any other way to solve this............

Comment: Hints: what is the net force on the spring if the spring as a whole is not accelerating (or better yet, if the spring is massless)? The spring has a force pulling on the bottom and a force pulling on the top. What other forces are those equal to?

Comment: @Allure No, it's solvable. Try computing the normal force as a function of $m_A$.

Comment: @Chris  tension and weight

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is framed such that the block B will **just** leave the ground. You must understand this is an idealistic condition. We are assuming that both the blocks have very less kinetic energy when they just start moving, so much so that it can be neglected.

In practical aspects, this is not the case. There, kinetic energy will come into action. But the question wants you not to consider that, as it's an *idealistic condition* of the practical case. You'll have to abide by the question.

Comment: even though we can apply this for block B ...how can we say the same for block A

Comment: You'll have to choose the condition where the mass of the block A will **just equalise** the forces on the other side. In such a case, it can be assumed that the blocks are on the **verge** of moving, but not yet moving. Don't take energy into consideration here, just equalise the forces on both sides.

Comment: okay.I got what you are saying

Comment: so we have to equate tension of the rope with the weight of the block

Comment: Yes. Equate the forces, not energy. Never equate energy in these type of questions.

Answer (score 0):

Your energy equation is not clear. Which,**exactly**, are the two instances of time that you are comparing? What about potential energy of both sides before and after? If you accept the reasoning that force on B should be Mg than there is no acceleration and velocity is meaningless.

Anyway, use the condition that the force equals Mg and find what that implies for m. It's one simple step.

Comment: I was comparing the time when the block B will lose contact which will happen at maximum elongation and since the block A has been released from rest then it will mean that it has kinetic energy  hence I used that equation

Comment: When B just loses contact, its velocity is zero.

Comment: yea I get it now but how should I solve for Block A

Comment: So B feels a *kx* force. What force does A feel?

Comment: kx in  my opinion

Comment: Yes. So now you can equate all forces.